# Algorithm for converting expression to binary tree

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I have an assignment in which I have got a formula, let's say `x+(y*z)` and I have to convert it to a binary tree. I have looked online and I've seen keywords like `infix` and `postfix`, and they will help to convert the regular expression to a form that can further be easily converted to a binary tree.

My only problem is that I've never learned this `infix` or `postfix` method, so is there any other way to convert it, or is that the only way? I've tried by searching up, but these were the only results I got.

It's a hard problem for me to solve without using online resources.

Comment: Take a look at detailed description of [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) - it is about converting infix (e.g. `x+(y*z)`) to postfix (e.g. `x y z * +`).

Comment: infix and postfix (and prefix) are ways of representing binary operators.  Regular expression only have unary operators, like the Kleene star and `+`.  Are you dealing with regular expressions or arithmetic expressions?

Comment: They are expressions with variables. For example, -x, (x+y), (x*(x+y))

Comment: Those are arithmetic expressions (the kind you do math with).  Your tree should end up having every internal node be an operator (an action like `+` or `*`) and every leaf should be a variable or value. These values should be atomic, which means you can't break them down anymore.  The tree for `3 + 1/2` Should be something like `(+, 3, (/, 1, 2))`

Comment: To chop up your input you can use the `tokenize` module, for example `for t in tokenize.tokenize(io.BytesIO("a+(b*c)".encode()).readline):` will loop through the tokens of the expression you are to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infix and postfix aren't methods per se as much as notations, or ways of representing the same formula. `x+(y*z)` is already in infix notation (because the operators are *in*side the equation). The other two notations are prefix (or polish notation), where the operators are before the operands (so `x+(y*z)` is `+ x * y z`) and postfix (or reverse polish notation), where the operators are after the operands (so `x+(y*z)` is `y x * x +`). Postfix notation is useful since it can be easily implemented via a stack (so to calculate `y x * x +` you put `y` and `x` on the stack, then we see `*` which pops `x` and `y` from the stack and puts `x*y` back into the stack, then we put `x` into the stack and then we see `+` which pops `z*y` and `x` from the stack and puts `x+(z*y)` back onto the stack and boom there's your calculation)

You can convert from infix notation to postfix via the [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) (Wikipedia explains it better than I could)

You can thus easily represent an equation in postfix notation via a binary tree since you go through the equation, adding operands to a stack as leaves, and when you get to an operator you pop the first two nodes from the stack and create a new node with the operator as the parent and the operands popped off as it's children. Then push this tree back onto the stack. Repeat until you reach the end of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

There are many parsing libraries available for this kind of work.

For example, using [pyparsing](http://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/):

```
from pyparsing import *

def rearrange(tks):
    T=tks[0]
    T[0],T[1] = T[1],T[0]
    return tks

expr = Forward()
arithOp = Word( "+-*/", max=1 )
terminal = ( Word(alphas, alphanums)
           | Word(nums)
           | Suppress("(") + expr + Suppress(")") )
expr << Group(terminal + arithOp + terminal).setParseAction(rearrange)

parseTree = expr.parseString("x+(y*z)")
print parseTree
```

will print:

```
[['+', 'x', ['*', 'y', 'z']]]
```